# How to accumulate errors in a functional way upon validating database object?

Tags: scala, salat

I have `Product` case class, which is returned by DAO layer (using Salat). User who is creating a product first time status of the product remains as "draft" where no field (of product) is mandatory.

What are the best functional ways to validate 10 of product's attributes, accumulate all validation errors into a single entity and then pass all errors at once in a JSON format to front end?

Answer (score 3):

I assume the core of the question is how to accumulate errors--JSON formatting is a separate issue and does not depend upon how you have collected your errors.

If it's really just a validation issue, you can have a series of methods

```
def problemWithX: Option[String] = ...
```

which return `Some(errorMessage)` if they are invalid or `None` if they're okay.  Then it's as simple as

```
List(problemWithX, problemWithY, ...).flatten
```

to create a list of all of your errors.  If your list is empty, you're good to go.  If not, you have the errors listed.  Creating some sensible error report is the job of the `problemWithX` method--and of course you need to decide whether merely a string or more complex information is necessary.  (You may even need to define a `Invalid` trait and have classes extend it to handle different conditions.)

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what ScalaZ's `Validation` type is for.

Comment: Hmmm looks interesting. Any links to examples? I feel like this answer could be a lot more useful.